# How can you read a Blob in Deno?

Tags: typescript, websocket, deno

I'm trying to read from a websocket in Deno. Here's the code (you'll need an API key from AISstream to make it work)

```
/**
 * URL used by the API; this might change if the version changes or at any time, since it's experimental
 */
const AIS_API_URL = "wss://stream.aisstream.io/v0/stream";

export const defaultBoundingBox = [
  [
    [-90, -180],
    [90, 180],
  ],
];

let socket = null;

// Creates a deno websocket client and subscribes to the AIS API
export function createSocket(apiKey, boundingBoxes = defaultBoundingBox) {
  if (socket) {
    return socket;
  }
  socket = new WebSocket(AIS_API_URL);

  socket.onopen = () => {
    console.log("Socket connected");
    socket.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        apiKey,
        boundingBoxes,
      })
    );
  };

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    console.log(event);
    const decodedBlob = reader.readAsText(event.data);
    console.log(decodedBlob);
  };

  socket.onclose = () => {
    console.log("Socket closed");
  };
  return socket;
}
```

The problem is in the  `on message`. Messages/events are received successfully. However the `data` is in a `Blob`. I have tried to decode it using `TextDecoder`, as well as `readAsText`. However, this returns `undefined`.

Using JS is no problem here: `event.data` is returned as a string, which can then be parsed to JSON. However, I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read the contents of a `Blob` as text, you could use [`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text) method.

```js
socket.onmessage = async(event) => {
  const decodedBlob = await event.data.text();
  console.log(decodedBlob);
  const data = JSON.parse(decodedBlob);
};
```

You could also use `FileReader` as you were trying, but you missed the `.onload` listener of `FileReader`

```js
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    const decodedBlob = reader.result;
    console.log(decodedBlob);
  };
  reader.readAsText(event.data); // does not return the data
};
```